# Cannot load Doc2vec object using gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am trying to load a pre-trained Doc2vec model using gensim and use it to map a paragraph to a vector. I am referring to https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec and the pre-trained model I downloaded is the English Wikipedia DBOW, which is also in the same link. However, when I load the Doc2vec model on wikipedia and infer vectors using the following code:

```
import gensim.models as g
import codecs

model="wiki_sg/word2vec.bin"
test_docs="test_docs.txt"
output_file="test_vectors.txt"

#inference hyper-parameters
start_alpha=0.01
infer_epoch=1000

#load model
test_docs = [x.strip().split() for x in codecs.open(test_docs, "r", "utf-8").readlines()]
m = g.Doc2Vec.load(model)

#infer test vectors
output = open(output_file, "w")
for d in test_docs:
    output.write(" ".join([str(x) for x in m.infer_vector(d, alpha=start_alpha, steps=infer_epoch)]) + "\n")
output.flush()
output.close()
```

I get an error:

```
/Users/zhangji/Desktop/CSE547/Project/NLP/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py:402: UserWarning: This function is deprecated, use smart_open.open instead. See the migration notes for details: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/master/README.rst#migrating-to-the-new-open-function
  'See the migration notes for details: %s' % _MIGRATION_NOTES_URL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhangji/Desktop/CSE547/Project/NLP/AbstractMapping.py", line 19, in <module>
    output.write(" ".join([str(x) for x in m.infer_vector(d, alpha=start_alpha, steps=infer_epoch)]) + "\n")
AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'infer_vector'
```

I know there are couple of threads regarding the infer_vector issue on stack overflow, but none of them resolved my problem. I downloaded the gensim package using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jhlau/gensim
```

In addition, after I looked at the source code in gensim package, I found that when I use Doc2vec.load(), the Doc2vec class doesn't really have a load() function by itself, but since it is a subclass of Word2vec, it calls the super method of load() in Word2vec and then make the model m a Word2vec object. However, the infer_vector() function is unique to Doc2vec and does not exist in Word2vec, and that's why it is causing the error. I also tried casting the model m to a Doc2vec, but I got this error:

```
>>> g.Doc2Vec(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zhangji/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 599, in __init__
    self.build_vocab(documents, trim_rule=trim_rule)
  File "/Users/zhangji/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 513, in build_vocab
    self.scan_vocab(sentences, trim_rule=trim_rule)  # initial survey
  File "/Users/zhangji/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 635, in scan_vocab
    for document_no, document in enumerate(documents):
  File "/Users/zhangji/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1367, in __getitem__
    return vstack([self.syn0[self.vocab[word].index] for word in words])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

In fact, all I want with gensim for now is to convert a paragraph to a vector using a pre-trained model that works well on academic articles. For some reasons I don't want to train the models on my own. I would be really grateful if someone can help me resolve the issue.

Btw, I am using python2.7, and the current gensim version is 0.12.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using either the 4-year-old nonstandard gensim fork at https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec, or any 4-year-old saved models that only load with such code.

The Wikipedia DBOW model there is also suspiciously small at 1.4GB. Wikipedia had well over 4 million articles even 4 years ago, and a 300-dimensional `Doc2Vec` model trained to have doc-vectors for the 4 million articles would be at least `4000000 articles * 300 dimensions * 4 bytes/dimension` = 4.8GB in size, not even counting other parts of the model. (So, that download is clearly *not* the 4.3M doc, 300-dimensional model mentioned in the associated paper – but something that's been truncated in other unclear ways.)

The current gensim version is 3.8.3, released a few weeks ago.

It'd likely take a bit of tinkering, and an overnight or more runtime, to build your own `Doc2Vec` model using current code and a current Wikipedia dump - but then you'd be on modern supported code, with a modern model that better understands words coming into use in the last 4 years. (And, if you trained a model on a corpus of the exact kind of documents of interest to you – such as academic articles – the vocabulary, word-senses, and match to your own text-preprocessing to be used on later inferred documents will all be better.)

There's a Jupyter notebook example of building a `Doc2Vec` model from Wikipedia that either functional or very-close-to-functional inside the `gensim` source tree at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb