# Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'neg_labels' when trying to use pretrained model

Tags: nlp, gensim, doc2vec

So I'm trying to use a pretrained Doc2vec for my semantic search project. I tried with this one https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec (English Wikipedia DBOW) and with the forked version of Gensim (0.12.4) and python 2.7
It works fine when I use most_similar but when i try to use infer_vector I get this error:
**AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'neg_labels'**
what can i do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

For [reasons given in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921588/cannot-load-doc2vec-object-using-gensim/61925728#61925728), I'd recommend against using a many-years-old custom fork of Gensim, and also find those particular pre-trained models a little fishy in their sizes to actually contain all the purported per-article vectors.

But also: that error resembles a very-old bug which only showed up if Gensim was not fully installed to have the necessary Cython-optimized routines for fast training/inference operations. (That caused some older, seldom-run code to be run that had a dependency on the missing `neg_labels`. Newer versions of Gensim have eliminated that slow code-path entirely.)

My [comment on an old Gensim issue has more details](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/419#issuecomment-128310355), and a workaround that might help - but really, the much better thing to do for quality results & speedy code is to use a current Gensim, & train your own model.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. If i don't use these pre-trained models and this fork of Gensim but can't for my usecase train my own model, where can i find a more recent pretrained doc2vec model?

Comment: I'm not familiar with other public pretrained models as of right now (June 2021), sorry.